# Redirecting traffic in apache-centos

Tags: apache, centos

I am trying to redirect all http traffic to https

So I want these 3 scenarios to be true:

```
1- http://domain.com -> https://www.domain.com
2- http://www.domain.com -> https://www.domain.com
3- https://domain.com -> https://www.domain.com
```

I managed to have the first 2 working but the last is not working. How can i achieve that?

Below is my vhost config.

```
<virtualhost *:80>
RailsEnv production
ServerName www.domain.com
ServerAlias *.domain.* domain.* domain.com
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACK
    RewriteRule .* - [F]

    #redirect all port 80 traffic to 443
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R]
</IfModule>
<directory /data/project/current/public>
   AllowOverride all
   Options -MultiViews
</directory>
</virtualhost>



<virtualhost *:443>
RailsEnv production
ServerName www.domain.com
ServerAlias *.domain.* domain.* domain.com
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /root/cert.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/cert.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /root/certCA.crt
DocumentRoot /data/project/current/public
<directory /data/project/current/public>
   AllowOverride all
   Options -MultiViews
</directory>
</virtualhost>
```

Comment: You can create another VirtualHost for domain.com:443 then redirect to www.domain.com:443. Actually it would be best to create _default_:443 virtualhost as catchall and redirect to www.domain.com:443

Comment: i have multiple domains managed by vhosts. will that be a problem?

Comment: Now that you mention you have multiple domains, then _default_:443 will be a disaster. The easiest is to have VirtualHost domain.com:443 then redirect to www.domain.com:443. Remove the domain.com in the www.domain.com:443 server alias.